# APNS in windows azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been implementing apple push notifications from windows azure. I have been able to connect to APNS server and get authenticated using the certificates. And I dont get any exception when i write the stream to the server. But for strange reasons the device is not getting notifications. The app is registered for push notifications. I am not sure what the problem is. Is there any way i can check if the notifications i send to APNS server are valid or even if APNS server has sent teh notifications to the app? Below is my code.

I will also appreciate if there is a tested and working code which is a better implementation than this

```
APPLEHOST = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
        APPLEPORT = 2195;

private void InitializeAPN()
    {
        applePushNotificationClient = new TcpClient(APPLEHOST, APPLEPORT);
        sslStream = new SslStream(applePushNotificationClient.GetStream(), false);

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(APPLEHOST, APPLE_CLIENT_CERT_COLLECTION, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Could not open APN connection: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("APN connection opened successfully.");
    }

 public void SendAPNMessage(string message, string deviceID)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

            // construct the message 

            binaryWriter.Write((byte)0);
            binaryWriter.Write((byte)0);
            binaryWriter.Write((byte)32);

            // convert to hex and write 

            byte[] deviceToken = new byte[deviceID.Length / 2];


            for (int i = 0; i < deviceToken.Length; i++)
            {
                deviceToken[i] = byte.Parse(deviceID.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            }

            binaryWriter.Write(deviceToken);

            // construct payload within JSON message framework  

            var json = new JArray(new JObject(new JProperty("aps", new JObject(new JProperty("alert", message), new JProperty("badge", 1))))).ToString();

            byte[] payloadBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            // write payload data
            binaryWriter.Write((byte)0);
            binaryWriter.Write((byte)payloadBytes.Length);
            binaryWriter.Write(payloadBytes);
            binaryWriter.Flush();

            // send across the wire 

            byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();

            sslStream.Write(array);

            sslStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("Message successfully sent.");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the simple binary format, which doesn't return error responses.

You should switch to the enhanced binary format, in which you send (in addition to what the simple API sends) a message id and expiry time, and can read error responses from the socket.

The Apple Push Notifications Guide was [recently updated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1), and now they don't even mention the simple format, so perhaps it's not supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the article, But is there any way that you can share some sample code in C#? Because am still unsure about how to handle the error response that APNS server might send. Because as of now even though the binary format that i send is wrong, it doesnt send any error response.

Comment: The old format never sends error messages. As for C# sample code, try [Push Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).

Comment: Push Sharp seems to be a handy library. Any idea if i can use it for commercial apps? As in is it an MIT license? Its mentioned as "Apache PushSharp Copyright 2012 The Apache Software Foundation", does that mean i cant use for commercial purposes?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not using it myself (my server is written in Java).